# Flex properties that "restrict" input but are not handled in Validators

Tags: apache-flex, properties, components

I have what may seem like a somewhat odd question. I'm trying to think of all the properties that can be set on Components that restrict/validate input in a way that are not handled by Validators.

For example, the "restrict" property can be set on Components of type SkinnableTextBase. restrict is a property that restricts input but a Validator doesn't handle it.

Another example is the "minimum" property. The minimum property can be set on Components of type Range and again it kind of restricts input.

So I'm looking for any properties like these.

Right now I have:
maximum
minimum
restrict 
maxChars

Thanks!

Comment: If you use a NumberValidator you can specify minValue and maxValue as part of the validation would would parallel maximum and minimum on a range.  I do understand the purpose of your question, though. Are you asking out of curiosity? Or is there a specific problem you have to solve?

Comment: This is mainly out of curiosity, yes. But thanks for the minValue and maxValue suggestion.